# output while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) in columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple question but i am missing something. I want the output of this query to be in 4 columns:

```php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
echo "<table>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {     echo "<tr>";
  for ($x=1; $x<=4; $x++);
{
      echo "<tr><th></th>";
          echo "<td>";
                        echo "<a href='http://localhost/loc.php?loc=" .$row['countryID']. "'>"          ; echo $row['country'] ; echo "</a> ";
            echo  "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I only get 1 column with all the countries or 1 get every country 4 times? what am i missing or doing wrong. it bin a long time for me php.

Comment: Why using that for loop ? and also here you are printing out only one column echo $row['country']. How are your other columns named.

Comment: Mudo i dont want to display any other column i just want to display the result of this one in 4 columns, maybe i should use "foreach" but i don't no how. the result is just a sinlge column with a lot of countries. i want them to be displayed in 4 columns or maybe 5, so you don't have to scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Select * From ...`
you need to use `Select column1, column2, column3...`

Comment: it gives me Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given

Answer (score 0):

I think that you print too much `"<tr>"` tag

try this code:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
echo "<table>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {     
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($x=1; $x<=4; $x++) {
    echo "<td>";
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/loc.php?loc=" .$row['countryID']. "'>"; 
    echo $row['country'] ;
    echo "</a> ";
    echo  "</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: thanks but i creates 4 columns with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)):
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <a href="http://localhost/loc.php?loc=<?php echo $row['countryID']?>"><?php  echo $row['country']; ?></a> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>

</table>
    <?php $result->close();?>
```

Comment: Gives same result,  all countries in one column.

Comment: What do you want achieve? The country column->all countries go there, isn't that what you wanted. What about the repetition, is it still there

Comment: I want to achieve that all countries are divided over 4 or 5 columns for display purposes so first country column one second country column two third country column four fifth country column one again etc.

Comment: I don't get it. How divided over 4. can you put screen shot there, to see how want your result to look like.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// this should be placed in some Controller
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `countries` LIMIT 4");
$countries = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $countries[] = $row;
}

?>

<!--and this in some view-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++): ?>
        <td>
            <?php if (isset($countries[$i])): ?>
            <a href="http://localhost/loc.php?loc=<?php echo $countries[$i]['id']; ?>" title=""><?php echo $countries[$i]['name']; ?></a>
            <?php else: ?>
            &nbsp;
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Anyway, you should not mix up HTML and PHP code. If it's possible try to use some templating language.

Comment: Thanks almost there , thanks for the tip about mixing php and html. it show only 4 countries in 4 columns, but now it has to go on throuhg the hole array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT `countryID`, `country` FROM `mydb`.`countries`");
echo '<table>
';
$loop = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  if ($loop == 0) {
    echo '  <tr>
    ';
  }
  if ($loop == 5) {
    echo '  </tr>
    ';
    $loop = 0;
  }
  else {
    echo '    <td><a href="http://localhost/loc.php?loc=' .$row['countryID']. '">' . $row['country'] . '</td>
    ';
    ++$loop;
  }
  echo "  </tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Note the use of backticks in sql, to esure you don't have trouble with reserved word.

Note also the exchange of single and double quotes in the echoes. Firstly, double quotes are the convention in html. Secondly, php runs faster. "php will parse this text," 'whereas this text will be read "as is."'